# AWT important or not for android development?

Tags: java, android, swing, user-interface, awt

I am coding in Java for sometime now. But many a times, in graphics and user interface part, the awt section is skipped or omitted and swing is placed instead and said that awt is of no use or less important. I wish to make android applications in studio.....so is learning and studying awt important in respect to android app development or should i jump over to swing and advance java section?

Comment: Skip AWT and skip Swing if doing Android development. Read Android tutorials instead.

Answer (score 5):

> so is learning and studying awt important in respect to android app development

No, as Android does not have AWT.

> or should i jump over to swing

No, as Android does not have Swing. Android has its own UI framework.

Focus on language fundamentals, threads, exceptions, and the like. I wrote [a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/02/java-good-parts-version.html) a long time ago outlining the key topics, though the Wikibooks links in that post may no longer work in some cases.